# "if" statements work individually, but not in an else if check

Tags: c, if-statement

I have the following two (soon to be three) functions, the issue I am running into is:

If I input the command "ADD" with the "LIST" command commented out it works great, and if I uncomment "LIST" and run the "LIST" command that executes fine. However if I have "LIST" uncommented and run the "ADD" command it will write to the file however it crashes the application giving this wonderful error :

> *** glibc detected *** ./server: double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000001680240 ***

Followed by A LOT more stuff under "memory map" etc.

```
/* Adds whatever follows the word "ADD" to the text file"*/
if (cmd.compare(add) == 0) {
    file_ptr = fopen ("file1.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(file_ptr, "%d" "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s", r," ", fname, lname, phone);
    fprintf(file_ptr, "\n");
    fclose(file_ptr);
    ++r;
}
/* LIST user input */
else if (cmd.compare(list) ==0) {
    file_ptr = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

    size_t count;
    while ((count = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, file_ptr)) > 0) {
        send(new_s, buf, count, 0);
    }
}

fclose(file_ptr);
}
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: This is a case where I wouldn't have edited the bad formatting. The horrific coding style contributed to or caused the problem.

Comment: @Blastfurnace You are correct, but editing actually revealed precisely _what_ the problem was.  In any case, his code is not reproducible and I've already moved on.

Comment: I do appreciate the help, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fclose is called twice during the add flow.  Proper indentation would help.

Comment: Where is it being called twice in the add flow?

Comment: @ff210327: You have a `fclose(file_ptr);` _outside_ both `if` blocks. Of course you can't see it easily because of the ridiculous indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Closing  tag problem ??? also **Alignment**

```
    if (cmd.compare(add) == 0) /* Adds whatever follows the word "ADD" to the text file"*/

  {

    file_ptr = fopen ("file1.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(file_ptr, "%d" "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s", r," ", fname, lname, phone);
    fprintf(file_ptr, "\n");
    fclose(file_ptr);
    ++r;
   }

   else if (cmd.compare(list) ==0) /* LIST user input */
  {
     file_ptr = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

    size_t count;
    while ((count = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, file_ptr)) > 0)
    {
        send(new_s, buf, count, 0);
    }
    fclose(file_ptr);
  }
```